# Getting the error 'Header mismatch: Expected RIFF but found' in my program with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to Tensorflow and have the following code in Jupyter notebook. I have a comment at the bottom where the error takes place.

```
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf 
import tensorflow_io as tfio
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'

def load_wav_16k_mono(filename):
    # Load encoded wav file
    file_contents = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    # Decode wav (tensors by channels) 
    wav, sample_rate = tf.audio.decode_wav(file_contents, desired_channels=1)
    # Removes trailing axis
    wav = tf.squeeze(wav, axis=-1)
    sample_rate = tf.cast(sample_rate, dtype=tf.int64)
    wav = tfio.audio.resample(wav, rate_in=sample_rate, rate_out=16000)
    return wav


lengths = []
for file in os.listdir(os.path.join('Glock45_Zoom')):
    #error takes place on the following line
    tensor_wave = load_wav_16k_mono(os.path.join('Glock45_Zoom', file))
    lengths.append(len(tensor_wave))
```

From the tutorial I'm watching, he has no issues with this line of code. I read on another forum that it could happen when the file isn't properly converted to a .wav file, but all my files are originally .wav files and I have no issues when testing the load_wav_16k_mono function separately.

The full error message is below:

```
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/95/f_mlphhj72qcv7tvg3831qm40000gn/T/ipykernel_26117/1357815659.py in <module>
      1 lengths = []
      2 for file in os.listdir(os.path.join('Glock45_Zoom')):
----> 3     tensor_wave = load_wav_16k_mono(os.path.join('Glock45_Zoom', file))
      4     lengths.append(len(tensor_wave))

/var/folders/95/f_mlphhj72qcv7tvg3831qm40000gn/T/ipykernel_26117/2892341374.py in load_wav_16k_mono(filename)
      6     file_contents = tf.io.read_file(filename)
      7     # Decode wav (tensors by channels)
----> 8     wav, sample_rate = tf.audio.decode_wav(file_contents, desired_channels=1)
      9     # Removes trailing axis
     10     wav = tf.squeeze(wav, axis=-1)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_audio_ops.py in decode_wav(contents, desired_channels, desired_samples, name)
    178       return _result
    179     except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
--> 180       _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
    181     except _core._FallbackException:
    182       pass

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   5881 def raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name) -> NoReturn:
   5882   e.message += (" name: " + str(name if name is not None else ""))
-> 5883   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   5884 
   5885 

InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__DecodeWav_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Header mismatch: Expected RIFF but found  [Op:DecodeWav] name:
```

I tried changing to a different folder (Glock9_Zoom) which also worked earlier in the code and still no success

Comment: We cannot validate if its a WAV file or not, they probably are not (that file does not have the right header).